# portforwarding in c# (matter with NATUPNPlib)

Tags: c#, iis, portforwarding, upnp

hi guys i use code below to forward port 9090 to my laptop

```
NATUPNPLib.UPnPNAT upnpnat = new NATUPNPLib.UPnPNAT();
NATUPNPLib.IStaticPortMappingCollection mappings = upnpnat.StaticPortMappingCollection;
mappings.Add(9090, "TCP", 9090, "192.168.1.104", true, "ProApp-SHARE");
```

and this code for firewall permission

```
string command = "netsh http add urlacl url=http://" + "192.168.1.104" + ":" + "9090" + "/ user=everyone";
StreamWriter ns = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + @"\fw.bat", false);
ns.WriteLine(command);
ns.Close();
Process n = new Process();
n.StartInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\fw.bat";
if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
{
    n.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
}
n.Start();
```

when i do this i can access my local website that runs on 192.168.1.104:9090 from internet , but after 30 seconds up to 1 minute its just disabled , and i have to run these codes again, can some one help me with this???

Answer (score 0):

UPnP is notoriously badly implemented in most routers. You might want to try using a different UPnP library to perform the port map. Check out [Open.NAT](https://github.com/lontivero/Open.NAT).

Comment: hi thanks to your answer , can u plz give me a dll and a simple example??? cause my visual studio is 2010 i couldnt open the project

Comment: Go download Visual Studio 2012 express.